# How to tell my controllers that my services threw an exception

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My controllers call my business services. I typically wrap those calls within try/catch blocks in case that my services throw exceptions.

Then I thought to move that try/catch block to my business services and let them tell the controller whether they threw or not.

So my business services could return an interface such as:

```
interface IResult<T> {
    <T> Data { get; set; }
    Exception Exception { get; set; }
    bool HasException;
}
```

And the signature of my business services would be:

```
public IResult<Product> GetProductByID(int id);
```

And my controllers would call it like this:

```
var result = serviceInstance.GetProductById(1);
if (result.HasException) {
    // handle exception here
}
```

My question is - which of these two approaches is preferred for testability purposes? Is there other pattern that I could use to indicate that my services threw?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want your services to throw exceptions?

Comment: No particular reason. But I recently came across an implementation of the command mediator pattern and the command handlers returned such an interface (data and exception, if any). So I was wondering if it would be a good idea to move the try/catch to the services instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer your question in a broader view:

You should design your system in a way that (hopefully) every common case is covered. If it makes sense that 
an item was not found in the database, and you have a special flow to handle it, **the caller must be able to get that information from the service.**
When it comes to coding, you end up with two options:

```
var res = serviceInstance.GetProductById(id);
switch (res.Status)
{
    case ResultStatus.OK:
        HandleExistingObject(res.Data);
        break;
    case ResultStatus.NotFound:
        HandleNotFound(id);
        break;
}
```

Or:

```
try
{
    var res = serviceInstance.GetProductById(id);
    //rest of code, basically HandleExistingObject() form above 
}
catch (ItemNotFoundException e)
{
    HandleNotFound(id);
    //This is the best case scenario. In many cases, you see something like this:
    // catch (Exception e)
    //... if(e is ItemNotFoundException && e.Message.Contains("dbError: not found")) ...
}
```

I believe that most people would agree that the former is a better practice. I won't get into pros/cons argument, but let me just add this: 
**The only way you can manifest an exception as a part of the interface is through the XML documentation**. too loosely typed, counter-intuitive and error prone. 
A new programmer could easily change to type of a thrown exception, without realizing other services are depending on that particular exception. Yet
it is a lot more rare that a programmer would break a strong typed interface.

---

**So, when should you throw an exception?**

Once you've mapped all possible flows in your system, every unhandled case is an exception.
When a service encounters an error it wasn't design to solve, meaning - your entire system was not meant to solve - the service should log all possible info, terminate the current flow (or request) and return internal server error.

These kind of errors can be generally divided into 3 groups:

1. *Request error* - unauthorized request, invalid request arguments, etc. Every kind of an error that the client is responsible for.
2. *Application error* - system design errors. For example, when ProductService is asked to add Product X to User Y, but user Y does not even exist (and it's not ProductService's job to create non existing users).
3. *Internal Service Error* - mostly coding errors (null references, index out of boundaries, etc.).

Such errors should be thrown as en exception as soon as they are discovers, and caught at the outer most layer of the application. If the pipeline looks like *WebServer --> ServiceA --> ServiceB --> ServiceC --> ServiceD*, and *ServiceD* throws an *Application Error*, there is nothing the other services can do about it. And if they could - that's not an application error! That's just one of the system's flows, and you should define a result status just for that (rather than exception) . 
The exception should be caught "late", on the web server level (*"throw early, catch late"*), and be translated to some internal server / request error.

It's perfectly OK to return internal server error
when your DB is not available, your application or server is misconfigured, or when  you have the simplest null reference exception (it's **not** OK to ignore those logs and not fix what can be fixed). Whenever you cannot 
process the request due to your own problems - that's when you return 50x error.